# Regex to match URL segment

Tags: regex

I'm really bad at regex and still learning. I'm trying to setup my regex to find my first URI below.

```
/test/guid/5824812d100afbc60ef09411
/test/guid/5824812d100afbc60ef09411/action/create
/test/guid/5824812d100afbc60ef09411/action/version/delete
```

I have my regex working for both the (/action/create) and (/action/version/delete).

I need the first to be it's own individual URI. The guid after /guid changes, but it never will contain anything after.

These are working:

```
\/test\/guid\/\d.*\/action\/create
\/test\/guid\/\d.*\/action\/version\/delete
```

However if I use the same convention to find the first URI, it finds them all. I need all 3 separate.

Help?

Comment: Reokace `\d.*` with `[^/]+` and add `$` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors are your friend here. `^` matches the beginning of a line (or beginning of the full string, depending on your modifiers) and `$` matches the end.

So all you need is something like this:

`\/test\/guid\/[a-z0-9]+$`

That should be good enough, since after the guid's string of alphanumeric characters you're expecting the string to either terminate or have a forward slash, but if your guid is of a known fixed length, it might be better to do something like:

`\/test\/guid\/[a-z0-9]{24}$`